# Parse XML in c# with XMLReader for multiple similar Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, object, soap, linq-to-xml

I have a response from a soap service. It looks something like:

```
<ArrayOfPaymentHistory_ST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <PaymentHistory_ST>
    <tTRANSDATE>2015-01-05T08:58:17</tTRANSDATE>
    <tPAIDTO>2015-02-01T00:00:00</tPAIDTO>
    <dAMOUNT>110</dAMOUNT>
    <dBALANCE>0</dBALANCE>
    <TRANSKIND>Auto CC Payment</TRANSKIND>
    <csUnit>Lee</csUnit>
  </PaymentHistory_ST>
  <PaymentHistory_ST>
    <tTRANSDATE>2015-01-01T08:58:17</tTRANSDATE>
    <tPAIDTO>2015-01-01T00:00:00</tPAIDTO>
    <dAMOUNT>-110</dAMOUNT>
    <dBALANCE>110</dBALANCE>
    <TRANSKIND>Rent Posted</TRANSKIND>
    <csUnit>Lee</csUnit>
  </PaymentHistory_ST>
</ArrayOfPaymentHistory_ST>
```

---

[image: Service Response]

---

I have defined a model like this:

```
public class payment_history
{
    public DateTime tTRANSDATE { get; set; }
    public DateTime tPAIDTO { get; set; }
    public double dAMOUNT { get; set; }
    public double dBALANCE { get; set; }
    public string TRANSKIND { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to parse this XML response and make a list of object of type payment_history.
I will then send this object on my markup and display in a table.
I found many post on XML parsing using XMLReader. I am still not able to find a good solution that can do this elegantly.

Here's my c# code.

```
List<payment_history> ph = new List<payment_history>();
payment_history p = new payment_history();

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

                    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(soapResult)))
                    {
                        #region parseXML
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            foreach (var el in reader.ReadOuterXml())
                            {
                                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                                {
                                    //return only when you have START tag
                                    switch (reader.Name.ToString())
                                    {
                                        case "tTRANSDATE":
                                            p.tTRANSDATE = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.ReadString());
                                            break;

                                        case "tPAIDTO":
                                            p.tPAIDTO = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.ReadString());
                                            break;

                                        case "dAMOUNT":
                                            p.dAMOUNT = Convert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString());
                                            break;

                                        case "dBALANCE":
                                            p.dBALANCE = Convert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString());
                                            break;
                                        case "TRANSKIND":
                                            p.TRANSKIND = reader.ReadString();
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    ph.Add(p);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }
            return ph;
```

Can someone guide through to make this work? I am new to c#. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

---

I tried following LINQ2XML. But doesn't return anything!!

```
ph = XDocument.Parse(soapResult)
                 .Descendants("PaymentHistory_ST")
                 .Select(g => new payment_history
                 {
                     tTRANSDATE = (DateTime)g.Element("tTRANSDATE"),
                     tPAIDTO = (DateTime)g.Element("tPAIDTO"),
                     dAMOUNT = (double)g.Element("dAMOUNT"),
                     dBALANCE = (double)g.Element("dBALANCE"),
                     TRANSKIND = (string)g.Element("TRANSKIND")
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Probably LINQ2XML will be a good solution, but I still don't know how to use it!! Anyone, please advise!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
XNamespace df = "http://tempuri.org/";

List<payment_history> ph = doc.Descendants(df + "PaymentHistory_ST")
                 .Select(g => new payment_history
                 {
                     tTRANSDATE = (DateTime)g.Element(df + "tTRANSDATE"),
                     tPAIDTO = (DateTime)g.Element(df + "tPAIDTO"),
                     dAMOUNT = (double)g.Element(df + "dAMOUNT"),
                     dBALANCE = (double)g.Element(df + "dBALANCE"),
                     TRANSKIND = (string)g.Element(df + "TRANSKIND")
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried its not working. Its weird that it doesn't give any error and at the same time the count of "ph" is 0. I verified that the service returns a valid response with many items..

Comment: I added a screenshot for your reference. Please advise.

Comment: Is there more XML than you have posted? Is the root element markup `<ArrayOfPaymentHistory_ST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">`, as in your sample? Or are there more elements containing the sample you posted?

Comment: In your screen shot there are more elements so my code could not work as it read out the namespace of the root element supposed to contain the target namespace of the data while in your screenshoot it is a different element. So I hard coded the namespace now.

Comment: Can you explain me a little why we have to add the namespace name? whya re you adding df in front of all the nodes name?

Comment: With the markup of `<root xmlns="http://example.com/"><child><grand-child/></child></root>`all three XML elements are in the namespace declared on the root element. And to select such an element with LINQ to XML we need to construct an `XName` concatenating an `XNamespace` and a string. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for details.